# X2Go desktop sharing feature for single application only

Tags: remote-desktop, x2go, x2goclient

I'm using X2Go to run a single GUI application on a remote system running Kubuntu.

> Instead of a whole desktop environment, you can launch single
>   graphical applications in X2Go... [source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-desktop-with-x2go-on-debian-8)

Also:

> If you want to use X2Go's seamless window feature, choose "Single
>   application" as session type, and specify the path to an executable on
>   the remote host. [source](http://xmodulo.com/x2go-remote-desktop-linux.html)

With that working well, now I want to use the  desktop *sharing* function of X2go so that **multiple users can access that same application at the same time**. All users need to be in the same session, exactly the way [x2godesktopsharing](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:desktop-sharing) works.

I have two questions about this:

1. How do I accomplish this *without* containers?
2. How do I accomplish this [with containers](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-use-the-x2go-remote-desktop-with-lxd-containers/)? (I believe the link I just found may allow me to do this with containers, but because I have never used containers before, I prefer option 1. Containers are a last resort. I would like to pursue option 1 before I try containers.)